# NSURLConnection and multiple asynchronous requests - is it messing with the data being transmitted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have an `NSArray` of links. I want to parse through them with an online article extractor API ([Clear Read](http://api.thequeue.org/v1/)), and with the result given back for each article (some HTML) I throw it into an `NSString`.

My problem arises from the fact that, say my array has 100 URLs in it, I loop through the array shooting each item into the API and getting back some results in JSON. This is firing like 100 `NSURLConnection` calls at once asynchronously.

I wasn't sure if that'd be a problem, but when I give it 100 URLs (real strings, none are nil) the data that comes back often has either empty values for the JSON keys (when they shouldn't), or the data coming back is `nil`. There's also a bunch of duplicates.

Should I be handling multiple asynchronous connections better than I am now? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If you're doing concurrent asynchronous requests and are using asynchronous `NSURLConnection`, then you'll want to define your own class for this download operation to make sure that every connection keeps track of its own properties. That way, everything can be encapsulated within this class where the resulting download objects can keep track of what's downloaded, what's been parsed, etc. If you're not using asynchronous `NSURLConnection` (e.g. you're just using `dataWithContentsOfURL`), it's even easier, though you lose some of the progress updates that `NSURLConnection` provides and/or streaming opportunities.
2. For best performance, you should do concurrent requests. Having said that, you should not have more than four or five concurrent requests going to any particular server. This is an iOS imposed constraint, and especially if you have a slow network connection, you risk having connections timeout otherwise.
3. If you're doing preliminary testing on the simulator, you may want to make sure you try out the "network link conditioner". It's part of the "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode", available at the [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action). There are issues (such as the aforementioned timeout problems if you have too many concurrent requests going to a particular server) that only manifest themselves in slow connections.
4. Having said that, you also want to make sure to test your solution on a device with real world network speeds. It's easy to successfully run massively parallel tasks successfully on the simulator that are too greedy for the device. Limiting the number of concurrent sessions to five will diminish this resource problem, but it should be part of your testing strategy.
5. I agree with JRG-Developer, that you should look into established frameworks, such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). Make sure to set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` for the `queue` of the `AFHTTPClient`, though, if queueing 100 plus operations.
6. I don't know how much data your 100 requests entail, but be forewarned that the app approval process has been known to reject apps that make extraordinary networks requests on cellular networks. What constitutes excessive cellular network activity is not explicitly stated in the app review guidelines, though [Avoiding iPhone App Rejection From Apple](http://mobileorchard.com/avoiding-iphone-app-rejection-from-apple/) has claimed that you should ensure that you don't exceed more than 4.5mb in 5 minutes. You can use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to determine what type of network you are on and perhaps warn the user if they're on cellular (if the amount of data approaches this threshold).

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a third party framework - such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) - and limiting the number of asynchronous calls happening at once? Perhaps this might help / solve your problem.

In particular, you might consider creating a `networking manager` class that creates and manages [AFHTTPClient(s)](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html), which in turn manages [AFHTTPRequestOperations](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html), for each endpoint (base URL) you hit.

Comment: I'm a little new to what this is describing, so would it be possible for you to flesh out the last paragraph a little more for me?